# How can I put musical clefs in the middle of text?

Tags: symbols, music

I'm setting a document that includes some music; I'm using lilypond-book for the musical examples.  However, there are some points where the author has inserted a musical symbol in the text; I'm using MusiXTeX for those bits.  Notes and accidentals are easy, but I can't find a way to put in just a clef sign.  For example, the author says

> The *G sol re ut* clef . . . is made thus, <treble-clef>.

I'd like to have a treble clef right in the text where it says <treble-clef>.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found my own answer after help from Seamus:

```
The G sol re ut clef . . . is made thus, \begin{music}\trebleclef\end{music}.
```

That is, of course, after including `\usepackage{musixtex}` in the header.

Comment: It is not necessary to surround the `\trebleclef` command with the `music` environment. It also works outside.

Comment: @clemens This seems not to work for `\bassclef`, as it is set too low. For example, take a look at the output of http://pastebin.com/bjQFjWAp

Answer (score 4):

Old thread but people who are looking should know that you could use `\usepackage{lilyglyphs}` as well. This requires the use of LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX and is well worth it.

https://ctan.org/pkg/lilyglyphs

[image: lilyglyphs]

Answer (score 3):

There are various packages that allow you to include musical symbols. See p.88 *et seq.* of the [LaTeX comprehensive symbols list](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Weirdly, I'm not actually sure the above document contains the "clef" symbols you want. (I don't actually know the terminology well enough to know if it's there) But if it isn't there, I don't know where you'll find it...

Your best bet might be to try and get musixtex to work inline... Searching musixtex documentation for "inline" gets only one hit, and it's no use...

You could print a pdf of just the symbol, and then `\includegraphics` it?

Comment: The document you refer to does not include the symbols I need; I looked at some length.  Maybe \includegraphics is my best bet; I can get musixtex to work inline for most symbols, but after I've inserted a clef, it takes everything after that as music.

Comment: Is there not an `\endmusic` command? or something similar. It seems strange that this symbol isn't easily achieved...

Comment: I tried the \endmusic (or \endscore, I don't remember which it is) command, but it did nothing.  It also surprises me that it's not easier.

Comment: Found it!  I should have been preceding it with \begin{music} and following it with \end{music}; \startpiece and \endpiece are not what I needed.