# How do I put a musical clef in a memoir-class document?

Tags: errors, memoir, unicode, music

I've got a lot of questions about preparing a book layout, but as I'm slowly going through the various books and other documents out there, I think most of the questions are being answered. However, the answer to the question [How can I put musical clefs in the middle of text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4093/how-can-i-put-musical-clefs-in-the-middle-of-text) doesn't work for my use-case, which is that I want to use a musical treble clef () as a section separator. I first tried with XeTeX and the direct unicode input (as shown):

```
\documentclass[msmallroyalvopaper,12pt,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont{Baskerville}
\begin{document}
\part*{1980}
\chapter*{Chapter One}
\section*{}
\end{document}
```

This didn't work despite the Mac OS X Baskerville font having the treble clef in its Unicode range (I know as I have a Pages document that does this); all that shows up is the unknown character box (). So, I try the solution in the linked question:

```
\documentclass[msmallroyalvopaper,12pt,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode,musixtex}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont{Baskerville}
\begin{document}
\part*{1980}
\chapter*{Chapter One}
\section*{\begin{music}\trebleclef\end{music}}
\end{document}
```

and this refuses to compile (I'm using TeXShop and forcing XeTeX), resulting in this message:

```
? musixtex/musixtex.tex:531: Class
memoir Error: Font command \rm is not supported.

See the memoir class documentation for explanation.
```

I have an SVG of a treble clef that I can use (I needed it for an earlier ebook book), but I'd rather just use normal font commands because I don't really want to have to worry about scaling this independently of the font size.

Does anyone know of a memoir-compatible solution for this? Or should I stop learning memoir-class and learn how to do what I need in ConTeXt or KOMA or is there something else that I should be doing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Baskerville font does *not* contain the clef symbol according to the Apple character viewer.  However, the Apple Symbols font does contain the character, so you can do the following:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass[msmallroyalvopaper,12pt,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Baskerville}
\newfontfamily\symbolfont{Apple Symbols}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsymbol}{\symbolfont}


\begin{document}
\part*{1980}
\chapter*{Chapter One}
\section*{\textsymbol{}}
\end{document}
```

The reason the `musixtex` solution doesn't work is that it is using very old font commands (`\bf`, `\rm`, `\it`, etc.).  Memoir prevents you from using these by default, but you can override it by passing the `oldfontcommands` option to the class.

Comment: Thanks. That does exactly what I wanted. I'm trying to match something I have in Pages and it seems to be "lying" to me in that there's an "invisible" font switch when I have the treble clef. One other question: in the document that I'm trying to emulate, I have the treble clef as a larger character (24pt as opposed to the main body 12pt); I should be able to do something like `\section*{\huge\textsymbol{}}`, right?

Answer (score 4):

A different solution, where you can choose the size of the clef without resorting to explicit font size commands:

```
!TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass[msmallroyalvopaper,12pt,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Baskerville}
\newfontfamily\cleffont[Scale=2]{Apple Symbols}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{}{{\cleffont }}

\begin{document}
\part*{1980}
\chapter*{Chapter One}
\section*{ is the G clef}

 is the G clef
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is also an interesting solution, but probably not what I want in the end. As I was playing with the code, I noticed that the `[Scale=2]` and the `\fontsize{2\dimexpr\f@size}` both double the size of the clef. I suspect I would only want one of them. What I will probably implement is a new command that I would use instead of `\section*{}` that scales to 2x the body font rather than the default `section` size (which appears to be about 1.2x the body font).

Comment: Sorry: I was experimenting and forgot to remove one.

Comment: I wanted to note that I needed up using a solution very similar to this one in the end for my document—as shown here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52946/formatting-a-book-with-scene-markers