# Formatting a book with scene markers

Tags: page-breaking, indentation, book-design

I'm laying out my wife's book using LaTeX; I'm using KOMA-Script `scrbook` as my document class, but I don't think that my question here is specific to KOMA. Between certain scenes, we have scene markers to indicate to the reader that either time has passed or the point of view has changed; standard fare in novels. It would look something like:

> …and we came to the end of the paragraph.
>
> • • •
>
> Meanwhile, in this other paragraph…

With the layout that I'm producing, I want to introduce two specific behaviours to this:

1. I never want a scene separator as the first text on a page. If I have to squeeze some vertical spacing to fit the scene separator at the bottom of the *previous* page, that's what I want to do. If it's better to move some of the text of the previous page (while avoiding widows/orphans) to the new page, that's what I want to do. I'd *also* like to do this with as little human intervention as possible, since I'm using LaTeX as an intermediate format for the print document.
2. I want the paragraph *following* the scene separator to not be indented, just as if this were the beginning of a chapter.

What I have made is a command:

```
\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\newfontfamily\cleffont{Apple Symbols}
\makeatletter

\newcommand{\Scene}{%
  \begin{center}%
    {{\fontsize{2\dimexpr\f@size}%
    \z@\cleffont{}}}%
  \end{center}}
\makeatother
```

So that I use it as:

```
…and we came to the end of the paragraph.

\Scene

Meanwhile, in this other paragraph…
```

Can I do either of these, and how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Paragraph breaks with asterisks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7381/paragraph-breaks-with-asterisks)

Comment: @Werner: I think this is not a duplicate. In the link you provided the ornament must be placed if and only if a page break occurs between paragraphs; here the situation is completely different.

Comment: @Werner; as the asker, I looked at the other solution question's solutions and they don't do anything near what I want out of my scene breaks. I always want my scene breaks, I just never want them at the top of a new page by themselves (I want it at the bottom when there is such a break) and I don't want to have to hand-adjust the document. I agree that they're related, but the question you've pointed to didn't come up in my searches before I asked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For 1. and 2. you can do something like this:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Scene}{%
  \par\nobreak\@afterheading
  \bgroup
  \begin{center}%
    {{\fontsize{2\dimexpr\f@size}%
      \z@\cleffont{}}}%
  \end{center}
  \egroup\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading}
\makeatother
```

or, to have even vertical spacing you could also say

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Scene}{%
  \par\nobreak\@afterheading
  \vspace{\topsep}
  \addvspace{\topsep\relax}
    \noindent\hfil%
    {{\fontsize{2\dimexpr\f@size}%
      \z@\cleffont{}}}%
    \hfil\par%
  \vspace{\topsep}
  \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I have to add more text in place to force this to happen, but I will be trying this and if it works, I will definitely be marking this accepted. Thank you!

Comment: This is…almost what I need. The problem is that it appears that \par\nobreak\@afterheading is preventing any blank space appearing between the last paragraph and the scene separator as seen here ([Missing blank](http://cl.ly/0i1a050t2A0p2A3A3B2E)). I don't necessarily need a full line space (probably a half-line before/after, in general cases), but I only want it butting up against the body text when it has to. This is what I want to avoid ([Bad scene marker](http://cl.ly/2k053D0G0Q3o3s1f0A02)).

Comment: @AustinZiegler: try adding  something like `\addvspace{\topsep}` right after `\begin{center}`.

Comment: That more or less got it working. It looks like the bottom space is a bit more (on average) than the top space, but I'm perfectly fine with that. It may also be a bit of an optical illusion. Thank you so much. I may just be able to get this layout system working for me…

Comment: @AustinZiegler: I've updated my answer with a new version.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful, and I can see how the second version works and even centres the ornament.