# How to use an asterism to separate sections?

Tags: symbols

I'd like to use an [asterism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterism_(typography)) to separate groups of paragraphs from one-another. The asterism shall appear in a line on its own, like in [this document](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/J_accuse.jpg). Can anybody tell me where I can find an asterism symbol (is there a macro that makes one from the asterisk symbol from the font you're using?) and how to use it as a separator as described above?

I'm using LaTeX with the scrartcl document class.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160336/asterism-and-similar-breaking-non-breaking-options).

Comment: @Hackbard_C I'll have a look into that.

Answer (score 3):

Here are three different ways, accorrding to rthe number of asterisks and their layout:

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{heuristica}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\newcommand{\triast}{\bigskip\par\noindent\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering\large{*}\\[-4pt]{*}\hskip 0.75em{*}}\bigskip\par}%
\newcommand{\threeast}{\bigskip\par\centerline{*\,*\,*}\medskip\par}%
\newcommand{\oneast}{\bigskip\par{\large\centerline{*\medskip}}\par}%

\begin{document}
\lipsum[3]
\oneast
\lipsum[3]
\triast
\lipsum[3]
\threeast
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I combined your code with the asterisk macro from the answer @Hackbard_C linked. I wonder if the koma script provides a semantic command for this kind of subdivision...

Comment: I don't use koma script, but conceptually, it could be a `\paragraph*`.