# Best Way to Produce This Chapter Divider Image

Tags: chapters, subdividing, definition, pgfornament

I am currently working on a document into which I hope to incorporate this chapter divider:

[image]

QUESTION: Does LaTeX have an ornament that resembles this triangular group of asterisks, or must it be produced from scratch? If the latter is the case, then how may I "define" it so that I can easily call it into the document at various places?

Thank you.

Comment: `sectionbreak` package provides asterism.

Comment: To define your own hand-made version, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160336/asterism-and-similar-breaking-non-breaking-options

Comment: @Cicada Thank you for your helpful comments.

Comment: @Cicada The answer given by Steven B. Segletes in the link you provided is exactly what I  was looking for. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `memoir` class (a superset of `book`, `report` and `article`) has a variety of methods for producing what I called *anonymous divisions* because they caused unnumbered and untitled breaks in the text.

```
% anondivprob.tex  SE 631043

\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{pifont}

\newcommand{\sometext}{Just some random text to help fill things up
  without necessarily making any sense. }
\newcommand{\twice}{\sometext \sometext}

\renewcommand{\pfbreakdisplay}{{*}\\ {*}\quad{*}}  % triangle of *s


\begin{document}

\twice

\fancybreak{\pfbreakdisplay}

\twice

\fancybreak{{*}\\{* * *}\\{*}}

\twice And a bit more to make the last line longer.

\fancybreak{\ensuremath{\clubsuit\quad\diamondsuit\quad\clubsuit}}

\twice

\fancybreak{\ding{167}\quad\ding{167}\quad\ding{167}} % \ding from pifont package

\twice

\fancybreak{\pfbreakdisplay}

\twice

\end{document}
```

[image]

For more information read the manual (`texdoc memoir`) **section 6.7 Fancy Anonymous Breaks**. It's only a couple of pages but explains much that it is not possible in this answer. For example, that you can have a break just of a missing line or two in the middle of a page but if the break is at a page break then you can a textual/graphic indication that there is really an intended anonymous break there.

Comment: Thank you for this informative answer. It addresses some things which I was not aware of. Actually, a couple of people on this post have directed me to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160336/asterism-and-similar-breaking-non-breaking-options ; and contained therein, I found that the answer of Steven B. Segletes  answered the question quite nicely. Thank you for your alternative approach, and for the addressing of other chapter dividers as well.

Answer (score 0):

This char is unicode ASTERISM #x2042.
You can type it from Linux Libertine in XeTeX

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
« savent bien la porter »
\begin{center}
  {\fontspec{Linux Libertine O}⁂}\par
\end{center}
Avant toute chose si on s'adressait à lui pour une guérison.
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit

It is a lot of answers about asterism, for instance

[Asterism and similar breaking / non-breaking options](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160336/119245)

Comment: Thank you for the link. It has also posted in one of the comments. In fact, the answer of Steven B. Segletes contained therein answers the question I posted entirely. Thanks again.