# Searching a musical quarter note symbol to insert into text

Tags: symbols, music

I want to simple write a musical quarter note in text. I however know that there is the `\textmusicalnode` available. But this does not give me a quarter note.

The usage of e.g. the `harmony` or `wasysym` package which would give me `\Vier` or `\quarternote` as quarter note  but produces erros in combination with the `amssymb` package. What should I do to solve this?

**EDIT**

This is what I include as packages in my preamble.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,bibtotoc,liststotoc,BCOR=16mm,headinclude,numbers=noendperiod]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic-verb,bibstyle=alphabetic,hyperref=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage[hang,small]{caption} % small and hanging captions
\usepackage{lmodern}    %% Type1 font for non english language
\usepackage{graphicx}   %% graphics
\usepackage{subfig}     %% to place graphics beside each other
\usepackage{listings}   %% to include code listings
\usepackage{xcolor}     %% syntax highlight in code listings
\usepackage{amsfonts}   %% number-symbols in formulas
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{xfrac}      %% slanted fractions with font fixtures
\usepackage[plainpages=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   %% fancy headings and footers

\usepackage{harmony}    %% musical symbols
```

I get the following errors if I use the `harmony` package though:

```
Latex Error: /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty:231
LaTeX Error: Command `\Finv' already defined. 

Latex Error: /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty:232
LaTeX Error: Command `\Game' already defined.

Latex Error: /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty:237
LaTeX Error: Command `\beth' already defined.

Latex Error: /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty:238
LaTeX Error: Command `\gimel' already defined.

Latex Error: /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty:239
LaTeX Error: Command `\daleth' already defined.
```

Comment: the following MWE works for me `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wasysym} 
\usepackage{amssymb}


\begin{document}
    hello world
\end{document}` could you post a MWE that doesn't work for you?

Comment: Older versions of `wasysym` had problems with `amsmath` or `amssymb`. Check that yours is version 2.0

Comment: may be [How can I put musical clefs in the middle of text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4093/how-can-i-put-musical-clefs-in-the-middle-of-text?rq=1) helps you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quarter note symbol from package `wasysym` can be used without loading the package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\providecommand*{\quarternote}{%
  \begingroup
    \fontencoding{U}%
    \fontfamily{wasy}%
    \selectfont
    \symbol{12}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
  \tiny \quarternote
  \scriptsize \quarternote
  \small \quarternote
  \normalsize \quarternote
  \large \quarternote
  \Large \quarternote
  \LARGE \quarternote
  \huge \quarternote
  \Huge \quarternote
\end{document}
```

> [image: Quarter note from wasysym in different sizes]

I would not recommend `\Vier` of package `harmony`, because it is a constructed symbol at a fixed font size.

The following file compares the the quarter note symbols from `wasy` and `arev`
and removes a substitution warning from the `wasy` symbol if `\bfseries` is used
(Only sizes smaller 10pt are not available as bold).

```
\documentclass{article}

% wasy
\newcommand*{\quarternotewasy}{%
  \begingroup
    \fontencoding{U}%
    \fontfamily{wasy}%
    \fontshape{n}%
    \ssubSeriesBXtoB
    \selectfont
    \symbol{12}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ssubSeriesBXtoB}{%
  \if b\expandafter\@car\f@series{}\@nil
    \fontseries{b}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

% arev
\newcommand*{\quarternotearev}{%
  \begingroup
    \usefont{U}{zavm}{m}{n}%
    \symbol{90}%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand*{\test}[2]{%
  #2%
  \tiny #1%
  \scriptsize #1%
  \small #1%
  \normalsize #1%
  \large #1%
  \Large #1%
  \LARGE #1%
  \huge #1%
  \Huge #1%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  wasy: & \test{\quarternotewasy}{} \\
  wasy-bold: & \test{\quarternotewasy}{\bfseries} \\
  arev: & \test{\quarternotearev}{} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Comparison wasy and arev]