# Write treble clef in tex?

Tags: symbols, music

How to write treble symbol in Tex?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clef

Comment: Perhaps you can start by looking at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/855/19384

Comment: Related: [How do I put a musical clef in a memoir-class document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51097/how-do-i-put-a-musical-clef-in-a-memoir-class-document) and [How can I put musical clefs in the middle of text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4093/how-can-i-put-musical-clefs-in-the-middle-of-text)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may find the [`musixtex`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/musixtex/musixdoc.pdf) package useful. In the documentation you find more complex examples on how to use this package. Here just two small examples.

**First**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\trebleclef 
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

**First result**

[image: First result]

**Second**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\startextract
\Notes\ibbbu0h0\qb0e\tbbbu0\qb0e\tbbu0\qb0e\tbu0\qb0e\enotes
\zendextract
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

**Second result**

[image: Second result]

***EDIT:*** Note that `\begin{music} \end{music}` is not necessary, I just recommend it, for it gives your code more structure and therefore makes it more readable.

Have Fun!

Comment: It is not necessary to enclose `\trebleclef` with the `{music}` environment.